# How can I add new Directory inside Lib flutter proy?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBJ39.png)

Hi, I want to add a new Directory inside lib folder on my android studio, I'm developing a new flutter app but the option is not showing, how can I add a new Directory, not a package.

Answer (score 2):

On my Lib folder "ctrl + shift + a" and search for "Mark directory as" then select option Remove from resource... that worked for me

Comment: Right Click on "lib" folder which is inside of flutter project and search for "Mark directory as" then select the option called "Unmark as sources boot".
This worked for me

Comment: this will disable indexing and so many other behind the scenes functions

Answer (score 1):

In a new Flutter project, a folder is called Package.

So you can simple create a new `Package`

Comment: what if I add multiple package inside one package? it looks like:
Login.ui.bloc and I want to add files inside every folder...

Comment: Should not be a problem. For me the option changed to `Directory` after I reopend the project... But everything is working fine.